# Mocha: Uncaught AssertionError: expected 200 to be 404

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, assertions

I am trying to test random urr. Which doesn't exits. So response code should 404 but it is returning 200, Which makes test case fail, Till here fine But it is giving `Uncaught AssertionError: expected 200 to be 404` How to handle this **uncaught Assertion error**.

```
it("Should return 404 when you put random url after /api/random", function(done){    

            server
            .post("/api/random")
            .expect(404)
            .end(function(err, res){
              res.status.should.equal(404);
              done();
            })        
  });
```

**Uncaught AssertionError** How to handle this ..

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected 200 to be 404
      + expected - actual

      -200
      +404

      at Assertion.fail (node_modules/should/lib/assertion.js:180:17)
      at Assertion.prop.value (node_modules/should/lib/assertion.js:65:17)
      at Test.<anonymous> (test.js:48:33)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:156:6)
      at assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:127:12)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:124:5
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:785:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:990:12)
      at _stream_readable.js:920:16
```

Comment: Open in browser that URL and check status - is this really 404. Maybe you have inpropper configuration and you are returing 200 instead of 404?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Thats why we use testing framework, I know this will fail. How to handle `Uncaught AssertionError` This is my question..

Comment: Why do you need to *handle* it? The assertion was raised, which is what you expected to happen. Then Mocha failed you test, which is what *should* have happened. (Or if the problem is that Mocha did *not* fail your test, then you need to make this explicit in your question and include an MCVE (rather than partial code).)

Comment: Please read in mean time - https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/unit-testing-nodejs-application-using-mocha/

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm in the quite same position.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need an error handler on your server/app/main.js that says something like this:

```
// catch 404 and forward to the error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

  // responds to client or test with error
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({
 message: "this is not the web page you're looking for. - obi-wan codenobi";
});
```